# VS Code / OmniSharp - how to set path to dotnet SDK / CLI tools explicitly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, .net-core, omnisharp

I'm using Visual Studio Code. On my machine, I have two separate installations of the Net Core SDK / dotnet CLI tools

- an outdated version (netcore 1.1) in the standard path `%ProgramFiles%\dotnet` and
- a recent version (netcore 2.0) installed to a different, custom path `%AppData%\...`

I need Visual Studio Core - and thereby, Omnisharp - to use the recent, i.e. custom installation. Unfortunately, due to my machine setup, the default "dotnet" command is registered with the out of date installation, and I cannot change this. Omnisharp is using the SDK from the same location as well.

1. Is there any way for a non-admin user to specify in Visual Studio Code / Omnisharp to use the dotnet tools from my custom location?
2. Any particular configuration setting or similiar?

---

For context, as to why my machine has such a weird setup and why I cannot do much about it, see [Cmd precedence: How to use correct dotnet.exe when installed in 2 locations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48745283/cmd-precedence-how-to-use-correct-dotnet-exe-when-installed-in-2-locations)

Thanks

Comment: try an approach with specifying version of SDK in  `global.json` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42078060/2833802)

Comment: That won't work unfortunately, as briefly discussed in the linked thread, global.json doesn't seem to allow to specify any particular paths; so it would look for the newer version in the default installation path (where it doesn't exist)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following Bogey's lead of 2018-02-16, and after manually installing the SDK per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/windows?tabs=netcore31#download-and-manually-install, when I was then following the tutorial at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/with-visual-studio-code I kept getting messages popping up or in the Visual Studio Code's terminal saying something like

```
It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs
Did you mean to run .NET Core SDK commands? Install a .NET Core SDK from:
      https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

But with a batch file in which I set the PATH environment variable before then starting Code, I am able to run the commands in the tutorial, eg, `dotnet new console`, successfully.

The batch file I created sets the PATH to be as it normally would (ie, as revealed by running `echo %PATH%` at a command prompt), but with references to SDKs not installed manually by me removed and with a reference to the SDK I installed manually added.  Roughly:

```
set PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\various\things;C:\WINDOWS\other\things;C:\Users\user1930469\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\user1930469\my_manually_installed_sdk\dotnet
start "" "C:\Users\user1930469\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe"
exit
```

With Visual Studio Code then open, I can confirm the value of the PATH variable in Code's terminal with

```
$env:path
```

and successfully run commands like

```
dotnet --help
```

Thanks for the tip, Bogey.

Answer (score 2):

Have found a bit of a workaround now, I've created a bat to start Visual Studio Code, in which I override the PATH environment variable upon execution and remove the outdated path.

This works for me now, but I'll leave this open in case there is a better solution such as a direct config of OmniSharp or such

Comment: Thanks for self-answering, Bogey.  Could you please share the contents of the bat so we can see how start VS Code with an overridden PATH?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: For MacOS, let's say your custom location is `/opt/dotnet-sdk` - you could do:
`export PATH="/opt/dotnet-sdk:$PATH"`


`open -a /Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app`
(sorry, don't know how to force newlines in SO comments)

Answer (score 0):

1 - install respective .Net SDK (click on get sdk)
2 - install respective .Net developer pack (see from output logs)
3 - close vscode
4 - open VSCode from terminal/cmd usin "code" command

Answer (score 0):

I found another workaround that doesn't require running through a bat file.

Add this to your settings.json, with your sdk path:

```
"terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
    "PATH": "C:\\Users\\Name\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\dotnet;${env:PATH}"
}
```

Then in your project's .vscode/tasks.json, change the type of any task using dotnet from "process" to "shell", and in your .vscode/launch.json add `"console": "integratedTerminal"` to the "configurations" section.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux users who run `vscode` via a desktop file (or via a shortcut on the panel and so on).

1. Copy the shortcut file from the system directory to your own one. This step preserves your changes after updating vscode to newer versions (your path may be different, it depends on OS):

```
cp /usr/share/applications/code.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
```

2. Edit `.desktop` file and replace

```
Exec=/usr/share/code/code --unity-launch %F
```

with

```
Exec=bash -c "PATH=$HOME/.dotnet:$HOME/.dotnet/tools:$PATH /usr/share/code/code --unity-launch %F"
```

where PATH=$HOME/.dotnet is the path to my SDK installation, change it if your path is different

3. *(optional some desktop environments can do this for you) Place this file into your desktop, panel or find/place it in the menu.